# In PHP which is faster ($x >= 3) or ($x > 2)

Tags: php, performance

A very minor saving either way but it prompted a mini-debate in the office and I wanted to get other feedback on it.

Assuming integer values for $x which is more efficient;

```
($x >= 3)
```

or

```
($x > 2)
```

**edit**

I have rolled back a wording change because one of the factors we discussed is that some believed >= to be easier to immediately read and felt that for int values > 2 was pointless because you meant >= 3.  This does not make the script faster but potentially more efficient in terms of maintaining it. (in before people explain how tiny a point this is)

Comment: There will be no performance difference. But the *meaning* is different for floating-point numbers!

Comment: But what about 2.00000000...1 - 2.999999...?

Comment: **I'm at a loss of words of how infinitely mindbogglingly irrelevant this question is.** When this question comes up, you're already waaaay beyond http://www.xkcd.org/554/. I nearly wish god killed a kitten every time such a question appears, maybe it would stop people from wasting everyone's time with them.

Comment: @delnan It is a coding question with an absolute answer. No one is saying this is an important question but it *is* a question.

Comment: Yes, it is a question (you will notice I didn't vote to close). But it still is as irrelevant as it possibly gets. Even common sense and five seconds of thought can tell you that this will never ever matter the slightest bit, performance-wise.

Comment: @Toby: Agreed.  And even if it may end up being a silly question, good and useful information can still be posted about it (such as Konrad's comment).  That is, after all, what SO is all about.  Share the information, let history decide if it's relevant.

Comment: @delnan - I agree to a certain extent. Not the most useful thing to know, but it DOES demonstrate an interest and competency. Even if it was asked in the past, many people don't rove the archives and happening across something like this may help some people develop the habit of actually thinking when they write code. Maybe it demonstrates nothing as well, who knows. But the web would be so much nicer if all programmers cared about processing and load times.

Comment: @Kai: I certainly encourage people to think. That's why I have a problem with such questions... with thinking (and maybe a bit of research, to be sure), every programmer (the cargo cult ones don't count) should arrive at "THIS doesn't matter for performance." And that's fact. Page load time sure matters, but there are a gazillion more effective ways to optimize this...

Comment: I voted to close.  Yes, it has an answer, but it is not a question that is worthy of being answered.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On my test machine (PHP 5.3.3) I ran 5 runs of 10 million iterations of each and averaged the results. "$x > 2" took 5.7357 seconds while "$x >= 3" took 5.8654. Note this excludes compilation time because compilation occurred only once for these iterations. So "$x > 2" is faster, but barely. I don't understand why, but there you go.

Comment: That doesn't say anything. Is the result statistically significant?

Comment: With a difference that small (0.13 seconds for 10 million iterations), I'd guess that it isn't significant, certainly not in general use.

Comment: I'm not sure this test proves anything — not even an insignificant difference. With a variation that tiny, it could just be some other process taking up a few milliseconds of time in the middle of the `>=` test. We'd have something if, with a billion iterations, it takes 10 seconds longer.

Answer (score 5):

I can't imagine the operations themselves will differ at all in execution time. However, there will be an absolutely miniscule increased time for the first one because the lexer/parser will have to deal with one whole extra character.

Definitely not worth worrying about

Comment: Agreed, but you know how nerds like to bicker.

Answer (score 2):

Empirical evidence will tell you.  Run your own benchmarks instead of running to the Internet to have other people give you the answer.

Comment: Any tests I run will be very small samples and with something as minute as this I thought asking the internet at large was the best idea.

Comment: So instead of running very small samples, run very large samples.  They will give you the answer you want.

Comment: Sorry what I meant was that will show me for the machine I am currently running the benchmarks on.  I have since ran some tests and agree with @alex (which is why I marked his answer as the correct one)

Answer (score 0):

`A very minor saving` is an understatement. Anyway I believe none is faster - there are assembly instructions for both

Comment: Yes... although it's not like PHP uses those.

Answer (score 0):

PHP will, in your case, swap the operand sand then run a smaller or smaller-or-equal comparison. If you look at the implementation of `is_smaller_function` and `is_smaller_or_equal_functionion`  on http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/Zend/zend_operators.c#1714

There you can see that th only difference is the operator in the last line

```
ZVAL_BOOL(result, (Z_LVAL_P(result) < 0));
```

vs.

```
ZVAL_BOOL(result, (Z_LVAL_P(result) <= 0));
```

So the answer depends on the C compiler, whether it can optimize either of those operations in different ways and the CPU.

There ight be a difference, but dependig on it might not be that useful and you should use the way which is clearer to read.